# ASP.Net MVC Toggling IsAjaxRequest property based on file upload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form all setup to upload a file and that is working fine. However the way my form is submitted is through AJAX.  The button that submits is still a type="submit" in case JS is off.

When I save my form the controller determines whether the IsAjaxRequest is true and if so returns some JSON otherwise it does a RedirectToAction.

When I don't specify a filepath in my input type="file" it considers IsAjaxRequest as true.  If there is a filepath set then it thinks that IsAjaxRequest is false.  How is it determining that?

My other problem is that when it thinks IsAjaxRequest is false and does a RedirectToAction("Index") I don't actually get sent to the Index view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is not in the `IsAjaxRequest()`? - it simply looks for `["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"` in the incoming Request. Look at [Mvc\AjaxRequestExtensions.cs](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/23011?projectName=aspnet#338547):

```
public static class AjaxRequestExtensions {
    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequestBase request) {
        if (request == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
        }

        return (request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            || ((request.Headers != null)
                && (request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest"));
    }
}
```

Comment: How if the filepath is set is the request somehow not appending with X-Requested-With? I think itmight be something to do with the AJAX I am using http://malsup.com/jquery/form/